# Как сделать что бы при нажатии на кнопку выводился alert с текстом и числом?

Tags: javascript, alert

Хочу что-бы при нажатии на кнопку выводилось в `alert` с текстом:

```
alert ("ты ввел (мое число)")
```

Как мне это сделать?

Answer (score 5):

Пример, от которого Вы можете оттолкнуться:

```js
const input = document.querySelector("input")
const button = document.querySelector("button")

const handleClick = () => {
  const value = input.value.trim()
  if (value) {
    alert(`Мое число: ${value}`)
  } else {
    console.log("введите число")
  }  
}

button.addEventListener("click", handleClick)
```

```html
<input type="number" />
<button>Объявить</button>
```